# Problema com edição de matriz fora do main()

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Então galera, eu tô numa dúvida extrema com o código abaixo. Eu começei a estudar ponteiros em C faz alguns dias e eu acredito que seja a solução pro meu problema, mas não sei como tratar o código.

O problema é o seguinte. Na função multiplicarMatrizes() eu não consigo acessar a matriz valoresC obviamente porque foi declarada dentro do main. Mas o problema é que eu não posso declara-la 'globalmente' fora do main devido ao fato de que eu preciso ler o numero de linhas/colunas de cada matriz no inicio do programa (não posso declara-las no código com um numero constante de linhas ou colunas).

Código:

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>

            #define G 5

            void lerMatrizes(int matrizX[][G], int matrizY[][G]);

            void multiplicaMatrizes(int A[][G], int B[][G]);    

            int linhasA, colunasA, linhasB, colunasB;

            int main() {
                int i, j;

                printf("\nInforme a quantidade de linhas da matriz A : ");
                scanf("%d",&linhasA);

                printf("\nInforme a quantidade de colunas da matriz A : ");
                scanf("%d",&colunasA);

                printf("\nInforme a quantidade de linhas da matriz B : ");
                scanf("%d",&linhasB);

                printf("\nInforme a quantidade de colunas da matriz B : ");
                scanf("%d",&colunasB);

                int valoresA[linhasA][colunasA], valoresB[linhasB][colunasB], valoresC[colunasA][linhasB];

                lerMatrizes(valoresA, valoresB);

                if (colunasA == linhasB) {
                    multiplicaMatrizes(valoresA, valoresB);
                } else {
                    printf("\n\nNão é possivel multiplicar matrizes neste formato. O numero de colunasA tem que ser igual linhasB");
                }

                return 0;
            }


            void lerMatrizes(int matrizX[][G], int matrizY[][G]) {
                int i, j;

                // Gera Valores p Matriz1
                for(i=0; i<linhasA; i++) {
                    for(j=0; j<colunasA; j++) {
                        matrizX[i][j] = i+1 * j+1;
                    }
                }

                // Gera Valores p Matriz2
                for(i=0; i<linhasB; i++) {
                    for(j=0; j<colunasB; j++) {
                        matrizY[i][j] = i+1 * j+1;
                    }
                }   
            }

            void multiplicaMatrizes(int A[][G], int B[][G]) {
                int i, j, k, temp=0;

                for(i=0; i<colunasA; i++) {
                    for(j=0; j<linhasB; j++) {
                        valoresC[i][j]=0;

                        for(k=0; k<G; k++)
                            temp += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

                        valoresC[i][j] = temp;
                        temp=0;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Eu fiz o código usando um numero constante de linhas/colunas, aí quando fui altera-lo travei nesta parte aí. Não consegui também passar a matriz por parâmetro, a solução seria um ponteiro?

Comment: Qual erro ou problema você teve para passar a matriz `valoresC` como parâmetro (da mesma forma que A e B)?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo alocar as matrizes dinâmicamente, e passar os ponteiros delas para as funções. Ex:

```
//aloca um array de ponteiros
int ** matriz = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * nLinhas);
for (int i = 0; i != nLinhas; i++) {
    //alloca um array de inteiros em cada posição do array anterior
    matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nColunas);
}
```

Aí a função `multiplicaMatrizes(int A[][G], int B[][G])` poderia ser `multiplicaMatrizes(int** A, int** B, int** C)`;